# How can I get the name of the file launched with my python notepad program?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import os
print (os.getcwd ()) # prints directory of the file, but I should know the name too
print (__file__) # prints name of script
print (__name__) # prints __main__
```

I want to know the name of the file, launched with my program (I set my program by default for text files and I could open it in my program if I will know its path)

P.S. sys.argv[1] is the true answer

Comment: Which file launched with the program ? I dont understand

Comment: If the user launches a text file, it should be opened with my notepad program

Comment: But to do it I should know the path to this text file

Comment: Wouldn't it be `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: _"# prints directory of the file"_ is incorrect. It prints the current working directory which may or may not be the location of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to use

```
import sys
sys.argv # array of all arguments when launching
```

For example when you run yor script :

```
python script.py hello.txt
```

You will have the folowing `sys.argv` :

```
['script.py', 'hello.txt']
```

It depens of your system but generally, when opening a file with a program you have this type of run